# C++ Regex from Visual Studio 2013 compatibility

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

This is a follow-up on a long journey where I've pulled my hair out extracting text from parsing GLSL shader files using regex in C++11 with VS 2013 rc5.

Here is the intendant result:

[Real time work editor here!](https://regex101.com/r/pK9bO0/5)

The C++ equivalent looks like this, which is a copycat of the PHP version:

```
std::smatch u;
std::string s = l_shader->GetData();
std::smatch u;
std::regex_search(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), u, std::regex("<(\\S+)[!]>([.*\\s*\\S*]*?)<[!]\\S+>"));
```

Unfortunately, std::regex_search doesn't return any results. I've been banging my head trying to figure it out. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you replace `l_shader->GetData()` with an actual string so I can mess about with it myself?

Comment: I hav had bad experiences with std::regex*, so i would suggest you to use boost::regex* instead. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Hi Andy! If you click on the link above, you could copy the shader data. I'll definitely take boost into consideration although, I'd much rather not use another lib.

Comment: This looks fishy `([.*\\s*\\S*]*?)`. You probably want `([\\s\\S]*?)`

Comment: Actually, it seems that \\s and \\S could be the source of the problem...

Comment: @neosettler: Since you never posted a follow-up, and didn't accept an answer either, what was causing this after all? Is this a bug in the library implementation, or was your regular expression indeed wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug to me. I can confirm that with VC++2013, nothing matches--but with VC++ 2015, each shader matches, as (I think) you expect.

Comment: Great... at least I'm not taking crazy pills. Thank you for your input Jerry. I'm not sure where to go from there though.

Comment: @neosettler: The obvious choice would be a different regex implementation--the newer version of VC++ and Boost being the obvious possibilities.

Comment: My project includes a few libs that aren't VS 2015 ready so I cant go that road just now. Hopefully, VS 2013 would have a compiler update  eventually, who know?!