# JavaScript regex will not match in C++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I've created and tested a JavasScript regex with regex101. After translating it into c++ (visual studio 2013) std::regex_search() returns false.

What's my mistake?

Working JavaScript regex:

```
struct[\s]+([\w]+).+?public[\s]+([\w]+)[\s\S]+?\{([\s\S]+?)\};
```

Failing C++ regex (with same string):

```
std::regex rgxGetStructs("struct[\\s]+([\\w]+).+?public[\\s]+([\\w]+)[\\s\\S]+?\\{([\\s\\S]+?)\\};", std::regex_constants::ECMAScript);
const char* test = "struct mySTruct : public boss { int test; };";
bool chk = std::regex_search(std::string(test), rgxGetStructs);
```

Comment: Did you try a raw string literal like `R"rx(struct[\s]+([\w]+).+?public[\s]+([\w]+)[\s\S]+?\{([\s\S]+?)\};)rx"`? Also please explain how exactly it's failing.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What syntax is that?

Comment: @qxz [Raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It just returns false. I also tried your literal string, with and without ECMA constant, still same result.

Comment: Tested this regex with gcc 6.1.1, and it works. This means that your regular expression is fine. This is an issue with your compiler.

Comment: @siskat It may be that VS2013 still had problems with implementing `std::regex` correctly and completely. I at least remember such issues where there. Do you have an option to update to a newer version? If not you should at least try with an online compiler.

Comment: @siskat See here for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127447/c-regex-from-visual-studio-2013-compatibility

Comment: Works fine for me. (`GCC 6`).

Comment: Thank you very much for checking the code! @πάνταῥεῖ It's my first time working with regex at all and instantly I have to handle with compiler bugs :D thank you very much for your hint, I ran the code through an online compiler with a newer msvc++ compiler and it worked well. It looks like I have to find an alternative way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After πάντα ῥεῖ pointed out that this failure is caused by a bug in Visual Studio 2013, I switched to the boost regex library that provide the same functionality as STL. Just a change of the namespace from std to boost was required to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> What's my mistake?

It's not your mistake. VS2013 `std::regex` implementation seems to be buggy. Here is a reference:

- [C++ Regex from Visual Studio 2013 compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127447/c-regex-from-visual-studio-2013-compatibility)

As others mentioned in comments, your regular expression works fine in newer versions of Visual-Studio or GCC.

Comment: Thank you! I switched to the boost regex library and the problem is solved

Comment: @siskat You may add that as another answer (with a bit more of detail). I think that would add value for future research.